# React lazy load image progressively from placeholder to a small image then a large image

Tags: reactjs

Is there any react library for lazyloading images progressively from placeholder to small img to medium image to large image.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple that support *two* stages (preview, final):
  - https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-progressive-image
  - https://github.com/wcandillon/react-progressive-image-loading

You might need to create your own if you want to progress through *multiple* stages, however (i.e., placeholder, small, medium, large). The source code for both of the aforementioned libraries would be a good starting point.